# why promise.resolve lost value inside of async function?

Tags: ecmascript-6, promise, resolve

I know when we use promise in JavaScript, we usally use two ways like below.

```
var f1 = () => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(10);
  })
}

var f2 = () => {
  return Promise.resolve(10)
}

f1().then( data => { console.log(data) })  // 10
f2().then( data => { console.log(data) })  // 10
```

But if i use async function inside of promise, Promise.resolve lost the value like  below.

```
const fs = require('fs')

var f1 = () => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('data.txt', (err, data) => {
      resolve(data);
    })
  })
}

var f2 = () => {
  return Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    fs.readFile('data.txt', (err, data) => {
      //return data              --> undefined
      //Promise.resolve(data)    --> undefined
      return Promise.resolve()   --> undefined
    })
  })
}

f1().then( data => { console.log('1,',data) })
f2().then( data => { console.log('2,',data) })
```

I think that i use wrong way about Promise.resolve,,, OR Promise.resolve not support async function... someone tell me why Promose.resolve fail..

Comment: sorry I was wrong. the problem is that `fs.readFile(` return nothing so the promise it contains are fulfilled. You need alsway to wrap with `new Promise` a callback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a value that you immediately want to resolve a promise with, you can use `Promise.resolve()`.

If you get the value asynchronously in a callback, you *must* use the `new Promise` constructor with the `resolve`/`reject` callbacks, there is no way around it.

Comment: I understand when i use callback, i must use the new Promise constructor. But Can you tell me why i can't use callback with Promise.resolve?

Comment: Because `Promise.resolve` takes a value and returns a promise. There are no callbacks involved at all.